# Get AWS caller Identity with C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, aws-sdk

When I execute this with the aws cli, i.ex. inside a fargate task, I can see the `UserId` that my application is going to use

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

with this output on the console

```
{
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::643518765421:assumed-role/url_process_role/6ae81f92-66f3-30de-1eaa-3a7d1902bad9",
    "UserId": "ARDYOAZLVOAQXTT5ZXTV4:4ea81f97-66f3-40de-beaa-3a7d1902bad9",
    "Account": "692438514791"
}
```

I would like to get the same information but using the C# SDK. I tried with the methods exposed in [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) but I can see some account related details but not the `UserId` assigned.

So far I've tried with this but I cannot see any profile when running in a Fargate task.

```
var awsChain = new Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain();
System.Console.WriteLine($"Found {awsChain.ListProfiles().Count} AWS profiles.");
```

My final goal is to get it and add to some task processed with Fargate to save a correlation Id in the database when something fails and easily find the Fargate log stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IAmazonSecurityTokenService` will provide the same information when executed with .netcore. Notice that the above example will only work inside the AWS domain as the endpoint is not publicly available if testing from a development machine.

```
var getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest
{
    DurationSeconds = 7200
};
var stsClient = hostContext.Configuration.GetAWSOptions().CreateServiceClient<IAmazonSecurityTokenService>();

var iden = stsClient.GetCallerIdentityAsync(new GetCallerIdentityRequest { }).Result;
System.Console.WriteLine($"A={iden.Account} ARN={iden.Arn} U={iden.UserId}");
```

Comment: Where does the hostContext come from in this example?

Comment: @Conor this refer to the `AWS` section in the `appsettings.json` to get credentials to get the token. `GetAWSOptions` it's an [aws c# extension](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/extensions/src/AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup/ConfigurationExtensions.cs)